# SOA in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, soa

I'm currently implementing a Services Oriented Architecture in Symfony2, and I would like to have our recommandations about it.

I want to know what I need to handle in the Controller, and what I need to handle in the service.

An extreme solution would be to pass the `Request` to the service, and it will implement all the logic (mostly Doctrine, as I'm developping an API and not a "full" site with Twig for example), and then send back a `Response`in the controller.

That means I would have to create code like this :

In the service :

```
if (null === $entity) {
    throw new \Exception('Not found.', self::NOT_FOUND);
}
```

And in the controller :

```
try {
    $service->doThings();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() === Service::NOT_FOUND) {
        return new Response($e->getMessage(), 404);
    }
}
```

With potentially one condition for every exception I need to throw.

Is this a good way to go ? Am I completly wrong about the implementation ?

Comment: Do not couple your services to requests or responses, that's the job of the controller. For handling communications between the service and the controller, I take the same approach.The hardest part is documenting all the exceptions that might be thrown and keeping track of them.

Comment: imagine to build a non request bound long time whatever indexing command, all calls it may make may/should be kept in a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is related to controllers logic (such as, take a request, response to a request, make a form, bind parameters, extract an entity from db (better with [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)), get and set session objects, redirects, and so on) should be kept into controllers.

Everything else could be migrated into services (or other classes)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand well, extracting from DB shoud be in Controller, but saving into DB in Service ?

Comment: @theofabry: it depends. I not tackle the problem every time the same way. If persisting an object to DB is also related to a return status or something like this, I usually prefer to keep it into controller. If there heavy logic that cannot be passed to some event listener or, better, to prePersist(), postUpdate() or those kind of callback mehod, I usually keep the code into services.